# Draw doubly linked list using graphviz

Tags: linked-list, graphviz, doubly-linked-list, dot

I've drawn a doubly-linked list using Graphviz (dot) as follows but the nodes are not aligned. How can I align the nodes?

```
digraph "Doubly Linked List" {
        rankdir=LR;
        node [shape=record];
        e [label="nil" shape=circle];
        a [label="{ <ref1> | <data> 1 | <ref2>  }"]
        b [label="{ <ref1> | <data> 5 | <ref2>  }"];
        c [label="{ <ref1> | <data> 7 | <ref2>  }"];
        d [label="nil" shape=circle];
        e -> a:ref1:c      [arrowhead=dot, arrowtail=vee, dir=both, headclip=false];
        a:ref2:c -> b:data:n [arrowhead=vee, arrowtail=dot, dir=both, tailclip=false];
        b:ref2:c -> c:data:n [arrowhead=vee, arrowtail=dot, dir=both, tailclip=false];
        c:ref2:c -> d      [arrowhead=vee, arrowtail=dot, dir=both, tailclip=false];
        c:ref1:c -> b:data:s [arrowhead=vee, arrowtail=dot, dir=both, tailclip=false];
        b:ref1:c -> a:data:s [arrowhead=vee, arrowtail=dot, dir=both, tailclip=false];
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

At a high level, the answer is `{rank=same ... nodes here ... }`
But, record shaped nodes and same-ranked edges give dot heartburn, or more accurately produce the following error message:

```
Warning: flat edge between adjacent nodes one of which has a record shape - replace records with HTML-like labels
  Edge e -> a
Error: lost e a edge
Error: lost a b edge
Error: lost b a edge
Error: lost b c edge
Error: lost c b edge
Error: lost c d edge
```

So, if we change the nodes to "html-like" shapes (https://graphviz.org/doc/info/shapes.html#href), you get:

```
digraph "Doubly Linked List" {
        node [shape=plaintext]  // for correct display of table
    {rank=same              // all on same rank
        e [label="nil" shape=circle];
        a [label=<<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellborder="1"><tr>
          <td port="ref1" width="28" height="36" fixedsize="true"></td>
      <td port="data" width="28" height="36" fixedsize="true">1</td>
      <td port="ref2" width="28" height="36" fixedsize="true"></td>
          </tr></table>>]

        b [label=<<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellborder="1"><tr>
      <td port="ref1" width="28" height="36" fixedsize="true"></td>
      <td port="data" width="28" height="36" fixedsize="true">5</td>
      <td port="ref2" width="28" height="36" fixedsize="true"></td></tr>
          </table>>]

        c [label=<<table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellborder="1"><tr>
      <td port="ref1" width="28" height="36" fixedsize="true"></td>
      <td port="data" width="28" height="36" fixedsize="true">7</td>
      <td port="ref2" width="28" height="36" fixedsize="true"></td>
          </tr></table>>]

        d [label="nil" shape=circle];
    }
        e -> a:ref1:c        [arrowhead=dot, arrowtail=vee, dir=both, headclip=false];
        a:ref2:c -> b:data:n [arrowhead=vee, arrowtail=dot, dir=both, tailclip=false];
        b:ref2:c -> c:data:n [arrowhead=vee, arrowtail=dot, dir=both, tailclip=false];
        // added :w to straighten edge
        c:ref2:c -> d:w        [arrowhead=vee, arrowtail=dot, dir=both, tailclip=false];
        c:ref1:c -> b:data:s [arrowhead=vee, arrowtail=dot, dir=both, tailclip=false];
        b:ref1:c -> a:data:s [arrowhead=vee, arrowtail=dot, dir=both, tailclip=false];
}
```

(sorry), but it gives you:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[Sroush](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70442903/2229960) provided a solution with html-like shapes, but I found a way using record nodes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67616977/2229960) as follows:

```
digraph "Doubly Linked List" {
        rankdir=LR;
        node [shape=record];
        e [label="nil" shape=circle];
        a [label="{ <ref1> | <data> 1 | <ref2>  }"]
        b [label="{ <ref1> | <data> 5 | <ref2>  }"];
        c [label="{ <ref1> | <data> 7 | <ref2>  }"];
        d [label="nil" shape=circle];
        e -> a:ref1:c      [arrowhead=dot, arrowtail=vee, dir=both, headclip=false];
        a:ref2:c -> b:data:n [arrowhead=vee, arrowtail=dot, dir=both, tailclip=false];
        b:ref2:c -> c:data:n [arrowhead=vee, arrowtail=dot, dir=both, tailclip=false];
        c:ref2:c -> d      [arrowhead=vee, arrowtail=dot, dir=both, tailclip=false];
        c:ref1:c -> b:data:s [arrowhead=vee, arrowtail=dot, dir=both, tailclip=false];
        c:ref1:c -> b:data:w[weight = 100, style = invis]; <- add this
        b:ref1:c -> a:data:s [arrowhead=vee, arrowtail=dot, dir=both, tailclip=false];
        b:ref1:c -> a:data:w[weight = 100, style = invis]; <- add this
}
```